# AJAX com Slim Frame

Tags: php, ajax, orientação-a-objetos, slim, laravel-eloquent

Projeto : https://github.com/noebezerra/survey-slim

Estou com um problema na requisição do AJAX (  resources/views/templates/app.twig   )

ajax - app.twig

```
$('.stars-default').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '../app/Controllers/Poll.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {valor: pointStar, qtdperguntas: qtdperguntas},
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
});
```

Ele envia a quantidade de perguntas da enquete que possuo armazenado no banco e um array contendo as respostas que o usuario seleciona. A cada clique em uma estrela ele faz a requisição mandando para ..app/Controllers/Poll.php

Chegando lá preciso fazer um insert ou update, mas...
...o problema é que ele não reconhece minha classe Controller e nem a PollAnswers.

Poll.php

```
<?php 
    namespace App\Controllers;
     use App\Models\PollAnswers;
     session_start();
     /**
     *
     */
     class Poll extends Controller {
         public function poll() {
            $qtdperguntas = $_GET['qtdperguntas'];
            $result = '[';
            for ($i=0; $i < $qtdperguntas; $i++) { 
                if ($i < $qtdperguntas - 1) {
                    $result .= '"'.$_GET['valor'][$i].'",';
                } else {
                    $result .= '"'.$_GET['valor'][$i].'"';
                }
            }
            $result .= ']';
            $userpoll = PollAnswers::where('id_user', '=', $_SESSION['user']);
            if (!$userpoll) {
                PollAnswers::create([
                    'id_user' => $_SESSION['user'],
                    'answers' => $result
                ]);
                echo "insert";
            } else {
                $userpoll->answers = $result;
                echo "update";
            }
        }
     }
?>
```

Comment: Alguéeeeeeeeeeeeeeeem ? me ajuda

Comment: Consegui. A solução é que você precisa criar um rota e mandar o ajax acessa esta rota.